# Salesforce Platform Event & CDC data volume understanding

Tags: apex, integration, platform-event, streaming-api, change-data-capture

Can someone explain me how many platform events  or CDC can be published at  the same time.
For PE I believe 10000 events at the same time, considering it would have the same limit as object records.
while for CDC I believe its 2000 events at the same time

And in general, what is the volume of data that can be exchanged via streaming API (PE, CDC, Pushtopics etc.) vs an API call.

Again there is a limit on the event size which is limited to 1 MB.

Another point on the event allocations part:
We have Devlivery allocation(50k/24 hr) & Publishing allocation (150K/hr). How does this get used up?
Taking the example from the salesforce [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_events.meta/platform_events/platform_event_limits.htm):

*you have an Unlimited Edition org with a default allocation of 50,000 events in a 24-hour period. Within a few hours, 20,000 event messages are delivered to two subscribed clients. So you consumed 40,000 events and are still entitled to 10,000 events within the 24-hour period.*

Suppose if we publish 50K events (does it imply same event types or all event types combined?), if we hit the delivery allocation what would happen to the further events that gets pubished since publishing allocation is more than delivery allocation?

Any help in improving my understanding is highly appreciated.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.